# send each row of a dataframe to different new dataframes based on the value of a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns: year, month, date, company, buses.

```
year     month       date         company        buses
2021      07      2021-07-17       ERSA           20
2021      08      2021-08-12       Coniferal      12
2021      08      2021-08-12       AUCOR          5
2021      09      2021-09-10       ERSA           23 
2021      09      2021-09-10       Coniferal      17
```

What I want to do is to create a new dataframe for each different date, and I want that new dataframe to contain only the rows that correspond to that date. Besides, I need the name of the new dataframes to specify which date they are referring.

So in this example, the final product would be three different dataframes:

- "df_20210717" which contains only the first row
- "df_20210812" which contains the second and third rows
- "df_20210910" which contains the fourth and fifth rows

It's worth to mention that in reality the original dataframe has over 2000 rows and more than 50 different dates, so I'd need the solution to be as generic as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split` on the 'date' to create a `list` of `data.frame`s.  it is better to keep the output in a `list` rather than creating multiple objects in the global env.

```
out <- split(df1, df1$date)
names(out) <- paste0("df_", gsub("-", "", names(out)))
```

The datasets can be accessed with `$` or `[[`

```
out[["df_20210717"]]
out$df_20210717
```

Or if we need objects in the global env

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

not recommended though (as only one object needs to be created as a `list` instead of 50 objects - based on the description)

Answer (score 0):

Here another possibility, but I would not creating multiple object or using `assign` without being extreme careful.

#### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L),
                 month = c(7L,8L, 8L, 9L, 9L),
                 date = structure(c(18825, 18851, 18851, 18880,18880), class = "Date"),
                 company = c("ERSA", "Coniferal", "AUCOR","ERSA", "Coniferal"),
                 buses = c(20L, 12L, 5L, 23L, 17L)),
            row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  nest(-date) %>% 
  pmap(.f = function(date,data)assign(x = paste0("df_",str_remove_all(as.character(date),"-")),
                                      value = data,
                                      envir = .GlobalEnv))

> ls()
[1] "df"          "df_20210717" "df_20210812" "df_20210910"
```